# example.herokuapp.com redirection to example.com - PHP

Tags: php, heroku, cloudflare

**Background**:

I have a basic PHP app deployed on Heroku, DNS by Cloudflare.

**Problem**:

My app’s Heroku domain is still active, even after I set up a custom domain. I want users to use the custom domain exclusively. In other words, my goal is:  When users visit `example.herokuapp.com`, send them to `mydomain.com`.

Heroku says to do this:

> Your app should send **HTTP status 301 Moved Permanently** to tell web
> browsers to use the custom domain. The Host HTTP request header field
> will show which domain the user is trying to access; send a redirect
> if that field is `example.herokuapp.com`.

I'm new to PHP (I'm a Node.js person) so I don't understand what to do.

My PHP project is only 2 files:  `index.html` and `index.php` which looks like

```
/* index.php */

<?php include 'index.html';?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're serving a redirect, you need to omit the body.

```
/* index.php
 * Redirect to example.com
 */

<?php
header("Location: https://example.com", TRUE, 301);
exit;
?>
```

Comment: You don't need to omit the body, but it serves no real purpose. All you need to successfully redirect is respond with a Location header and a HTTP status code of 3XX.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options, either you can redirect at server level ( may be you apache or nginx depends on whta youbare using) or you can redirect with php. I would recommend via seever as this will be more safe and quick.